# Amazon EC2 instance ssh problems

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, server-setup

I`m new to EC2 and I'm having some problems setting up my first instance. I followed this guide:
http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/01/26/starting-amazon-ec2-with-mac-os-x/
with the difference that I used

```
ec2-run-instances --instance-type t1.micro ami-7f418316 -k ec2-keypair
```

to create my instance. When I try going to the public dns provided (ec2-107-22-254-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com) I can't load the page. I tried running the command

```
ssh -i ec2-keypair root@ec2-107-22-254-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

but received this message in the terminal:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ec2-107-22-254-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com/: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

How do I properly set up a free micro instance on EC2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to leave the trailing slash off of the hostname when you ssh.  I.e.,

```
ssh -i ec2-keypair root@ec2-107-22-254-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Tip: Instead of asking Amazon to create your ssh keypair for you, you  can upload your own ssh public key to EC2. This makes the ssh command much easier as you don't have to always specify "-i ec2-keypair".

I wrote an article that describes how to set this up:

> Uploading Personal ssh Keys to Amazon EC2
>   http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys

Comment: Actually, it turns out I also need to use ec2-user instead of root, so it will be: ssh -i ec2-keypair ec2-user@ec2-107-22-254-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: You can also put the EC2 keypair in your ~/.ssh/config.